# Connect MySQL not using local host

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to connect to mySQL DB in python, not through my local host, when I connect through localhost I do it like this

```
db  = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='my-pass', db='my-database')
```

But now I am not sure what do I put as the host, in this line of code, everything else will be the same, but what do I put as the host, when Im not local?

Or do I need to make a new user to do this, if possible I would like to do with same user.

Thanks

Comment: I believe this question has been answered [Over Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33978879). That link is to a question from the same op. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Server's IP

```
db  = MySQLdb.connect(host='mysql4.host.something', user='root', passwd='my-pass', db='my-database')
```

Comment: what is 'mysql4.host.something', is that the servers IP that I am currently on or the IP of the server I am trying to connect to?

Comment: The server you are trying to connect to, aka the server that will be hosting you.

Comment: okay I put in the server I am trying to connect to, and I got this error `1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'me.myhost.com' (using password: YES)")`

Comment: Your host should provide you with login information, which you want to use. So user will be your login and passw will be your password. db will be the database you are trying to access.

Comment: yes I have the correct username and password and database name for the database

Comment: Then you either don't have correct privileges, or there was a typo. Try contacting your host.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to know your hosts IP adress. You can ping your webside on command.

2) Your host parameter should be your IP adress

3) You need to create your database on your Cpanel or Plesk panel and have to write username and password parameters. You create the user while creating the database.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't clarify I am on server B and mySQL database is in serve A, and I want to access the database on server A form server B

Comment: Okey i understand clearly now. You will need a static IP adress on server A

Comment: okay and then what do I do with that?

Comment: I dont know too much about this work but you need to input your IP adress of B on Remote Database Access Hosts on server A. On server B connect to the Ip of A

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of practice, you should not be using user 'root' to query the database. 'root' is intended to be used strictly for database administration tasks such as starting, stopping, backing up, managing user accounts &c.

You should create a new user `'spenf10'@'%'` (the `@'%'` part will allow you to log in from any IP address or hostname), then `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'spenf10'@'%'` to give yourself access to all the data, and use that user account for all data access. (Change 'spenf10' to whatever name you want to use.)

***NOTE*** I am assuming you own the server where you want to do this, ie. it is the same box you connected to via *localhost*. If this is not the case, you will have to discuss the matter with the person who *does* own the box.

Comment: I own both the server I am connecting with and trying to connect to, if that is what you mean by the NOTE. And I just tried what you suggested and got an error as I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978772/1045-access-denied-for-user-usernamenot-local-using-password-yes, if you wouldn't mind taking a look