# 1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'NOT-local' (using password: YES)"

Tags: python, mysql

I have a user in mySQL database like this

[image]

And I am trying to login to mySQL on serverA from server B, in python, here is what I am currently doing,

```
db  = MySQLdb.connect(host='IP-address-server-A', user='username', passwd='my-password', db='my-database')
```

And I am getting this error

```
(1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'serverB' (using password: YES)")
```

What is going on, and why can't I connect?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you granted permission to `my-database` for `username` from `serverB`?  I'm betting you have not and that you could not connect to the MySQL server from the command line on ServerB either, not just programmatically

Comment: @EricRenouf I though doing username@% allowed it from all servers

Comment: Log in as root and issue `SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user;` and check that there's a record for `user 'username', host '%'`. Also note whether there's a value in the `password` column; if not then don't specify a password in the connect string.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax there is a record of `'username'`, at the host `'%'` and there is a `password` present for that column

Comment: seen this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267114/python-mysqldb-error-1045-access-denied-for-user). i hope meet your answer.

Comment: Did you issue the `GRANT` command I suggested in the other thread?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax yes I did that, and when I look at it under the 'global privileges' column I see `ALL PRIVILEGES`, I currently am using a password when I try to login as `username`

Comment: Either `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` or restart the server? The article linked by @virendra should cover everything you need to do.

Comment: I just found [a question on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182675/mysql-remote-and-local-access "mysql-remote-and-local-access") that might prove helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

show logins to the server (note that `%` means anyhost or wildcard)

```
select user,host from mysql.user;

+-----------+------------+
| user      | host       |
+-----------+------------+
| ajax_guy  | %          |
| joe7      | %          |
| joe8      | %          |
+-----------+------------+
```

show what grants exist for a certain user.

```
show grants for 'ajax_guy'@'%';

+----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Grants for ajax_guy@%                                              
+----------------------------------------------------------------------
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'ajax_guy'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ...
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ajax_stuff`.* TO 'ajax_guy'@'%'           
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ajax_stuff`.`ajax_stuff` TO 'ajax_guy'@'%'
+----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to grant access to a certain db to a certain login.
Below we are granting all rights to the user to the `so_gibberish` **database**.

```
grant ALL on so_gibberish.* to 'ajax_guy'@'%';
```

Look at grants in effect *now* for that login

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Grants for ajax_guy@%                                              
+----------------------------------------------------------------------
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'ajax_guy'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ...
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ajax_stuff`.* TO 'ajax_guy'@'%'           
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `so_gibberish`.* TO 'ajax_guy'@'%'         
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ajax_stuff`.`ajax_stuff` TO 'ajax_guy'@'%'
+----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Create a new login `drew_saturday` with a password `friday987`.
He has all privileges on **database** `so_gibberish` and can login from any host (`%`)

```
grant ALL on so_gibberish.* to 'drew_saturday'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'friday987';

select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='drew_saturday';

+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| user          | host | password                                  |
+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| drew_saturday | %    | *4600ED0F377308959665877BD327D4788DC2071F |
+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

That password above is the hashed password by the way.

Note: for MySQL 5.7 the command above would be:

```
select user,host,authentication_string from mysql.user where user='drew_saturday';
```

Mysql manual page on [Grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html). Do not grant excessive rights to users using `grant ALL on *. ...`. That would be for *all* database in the system. Just read the manual and less is more.

Sometimes, admins want to grant access to just a handful of tables in a database (not all tables in it) to a login. The manual is a must read on this.

---

And one last thing. 'drew_saturday'@'%' is a different login than 'drew_saturday'@'NOT-local' (borrowing from your title). They are different logins with different rights. That is the point of the first thing I wrote way up there.

Comment: is `so_gibberish` the name of the database you are granting access to, for the user `ajax_guy`?

Comment: great, thanks so much. I'm just wondering why do I need to create a second user why can't it all be done with one? if you know what I mean, in your example you have `ajax_guy` and `drew_saturday`

Comment: First off I was showing you what pre-existed in my system. Then I showed how to create a user with a password and grant all at once. There are different audiences reading this once you are gone. My answer is for all. Everyone finds their own nugget, perhaps. Sometimes people get frustrated and say hey I wanna just drop all my users here it is so screwed up. etc

Comment: Makes sense, great answer