# Can't connect to MySQL database in cpanel using python

Tags: python, mysql, cpanel

I want to connect the database(mysql) in `cpanel` using python. But I don't know how to connect with `cpanel` using python.

I've tried with the following code using `pymysql` module in python:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.connect("ipaddress","user","password","database_name")
```

I get the following error while connecting to mysql:

> OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'DELL' (using password: YES)")

Comment: Did you assign any user on your database?

Comment: yes i already done it. still getting the same problem.

Comment: @B.SamareshYadav Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978879/7519419

Comment: thanks for sending this. please tell me where should i write the query. i am writing the query inside the server of contains phpmyadmin is it ok

Comment: @B.SamareshYadav as long as you are connected to your MySQL server it is fine. Are you using command-line interface?